# @AvroRecord in scala does not resolve scalamacro plugin

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, avro, scala-macros

I'm trying to integrate them with AvroSchema to encode / decode messages as case class scala. I'm using as a scala version 2.10.4 and as a library "com.julianpeeters"% "avro-scale-macro-annotations_2.10"% "0.4.9". In build.sbt I added this plugin for completing, but unfortunately is not resolved addCompilerPlugin ( "org.scalamacros"% "paradise"% "2.1.0" cross CrossVersion.full). I read many guides that simply say to add it by hand development in the IDE (in my case intellij). I've done with this solution unfortunately without success. I always get the error under which you back.

```
[error] 
[error]   last tree to typer: Ident(String)
[error]               symbol: <none> (flags: )
[error]    symbol definition: <none>
[error]        symbol owners: 
[error]       context owners: package domain
[error] 
[error] == Enclosing template or block ==
[error] 
[error] Import(
[error]   "com"."julianpeeters"."avro"."annotations"
[error]   List(
[error]     ImportSelector(AvroRecord,81,AvroRecord,81)
[error]   )
[error] )
[error] 
[error] no-symbol does not have an owner
[error]     at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.abort(SymbolTable.scala:49)
[error]     at scala.tools.nsc.Global.abort(Global.scala:254)
[error]     at scala.reflect.internal.Symbols$NoSymbol.owner(Symbols.scala:3257)
[error]     at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.scala$tools$nsc$typechecker$Typers$Typer$$typedTypeDefImpl(Typers.scala:2318)
[error]     at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedTypeDef(Typers.scala:2298)
[error]     at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed1(Typers.scala:5585)
[error]     at org.scalamacros.paradise.typechecker.Analyzer$$anon$1.org$scalamacros$paradise$typechecker$Typers$ParadiseTyper$$super$typed1(Analyzer.scala:19)
[error]     at org.scalamacros.paradise.typechecker.Typers$ParadiseTyper$class.typed1(Typers.scala:44)
[error]     at org.scalamacros.paradise.typechecker.Analyzer$$anon$1.typed1(Analyzer.scala:19)
[error]     at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed(Typers.scala:5642)
[error]     at scala.reflect.macros.runtime.Typers$$anonfun$typeCheck$2$$anonfun$5.apply(Typers.scala:25)
[error]     at scala.reflect.macros.runtime.Typers$$anonfun$typeCheck$2$$anonfun$5.apply(Typers.scala:25)
[error]     at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.silent(Typers.scala:727)
[error]     at scala.reflect.macros.runtime.Typers$$anonfun$typeCheck$2.apply(Typers.scala:25)
[error]     at scala.reflect.macros.runtime.Typers$$anonfun$typeCheck$2.apply(Typers.scala:25)
[error]     at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Contexts$Context.withMacrosEnabled(Contexts.scala:242)
[error]     at scala.reflect.macros.runtime.Typers$$anonfun$3.apply(Typers.scala:18)
[error]     at scala.reflect.macros.runtime.Typers$$anonfun$3.apply(Typers.scala:18)
[error]     at scala.reflect.macros.runtime.Typers$$anonfun$wrapper$1$1.apply(Typers.scala:19)
[error]     at scala.reflect.macros.runtime.Typers$$anonfun$wrapper$1$1.apply(Typers.scala:19)
[error]     at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Contexts$Context.withImplicitsEnabled(Contexts.scala:211)
[error]     at scala.reflect.macros.runtime.Typers$$anonfun$1.apply(Typers.scala:17)
[error]     at scala.reflect.macros.runtime.Typers$$anonfun$1.apply(Typers.scala:17)
[error]     at scala.reflect.macros.runtime.Typers$class.wrapper$1(Typers.scala:19)
[error]     at scala.reflect.macros.runtime.Typers$class.typeCheck(Typers.scala:25)
[error]     at scala.reflect.macros.runtime.Context.typeCheck(Context.scala:6)
[error]     at scala.reflect.macros.runtime.Context.typeCheck(Context.scala:6)
[error]     at com.julianpeeters.avro.annotations.AvroRecordMacro$$anonfun$indexFields$1$1.apply(AvroRecordMacro.scala:228)
[error]     at com.julianpeeters.avro.annotations.AvroRecordMacro$$anonfun$indexFields$1$1.apply(AvroRecordMacro.scala:226)
[error]     at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
[error]     at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
[error]     at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
[error]     at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:244)
[error]     at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:105)
[error]     at com.julianpeeters.avro.annotations.AvroRecordMacro$.indexFields$1(AvroRecordMacro.scala:226)
[error]     at com.julianpeeters.avro.annotations.AvroRecordMacro$.impl(AvroRecordMacro.scala:238)
[error] @AvroRecord
[error]  ^
```

Snippet of my build.sbt:

```
scalaVersion := "2.10.4"
resolvers ++= Seq(
  Resolver.sonatypeRepo("releases"),
  "typesafe-repository" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/",
  "clojars-repository" at "https://clojars.org/repo"
)
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
...
  "com.julianpeeters" % "avro-scala-macro-annotations_2.10" % "0.4.9",
  "com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat" % "jackson-dataformat-smile" % "2.2.3"
)
```

and finally the offending line that does not solve:

```
addCompilerPlugin("org.scalamacros" % "paradise" % "2.1.0" cross CrossVersion.full)
```

Thanks